# Looking for the name of this two player patience game

Tags: identify-this-game, playing-cards

The game is played with a single shuffled deck. Cards are dealt face down to each player in turn until all the cards have been dealt. The non-dealer goes first and puts a card face up onto what becomes the pile. If the card is a non-picture card, it is the next player's turn.

If it is a picture card, then the other player must play the following number of cards:

```
Jack - 1 card
Queen - 2 cards
King - 3 cards
Ace - 4 cards
```

If no picture cards are played, then the hand is won and the player gathers the cards and puts them at the bottom of his deck. If a picture card is played, play immediately moves to the next person.

The objective of the game is to win all the cards.

As may be evident from the above description: no skill is involved at all, it is purely a game of chance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the classic game ["Beggar-my-neighbour"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beggar-my-neighbour), or "Strip Jack Naked" as it is also known.

Comment: Thanks. Our family has always known this game as "Toad in the hole", but I'm guessing this was a regional name of some sort.

Comment: Adding to the list of names, a nearly identical game (*but including slap rules, e.g. first to slap if two cards of same value in a row are played gets to take the pile*) would be [Egyptian Rat Screw](https://bicyclecards.com/how-to-play/egyptian-rat-screw/) which has rules available on the official bicycle cards website.